# Explanation for taking a derivative with respect to a different variable vs itself - $\frac{d}{dx}[y^2]$ vs $\frac{d}{dx}[x^2]$

Tags: derivatives, notation

I believe $\dfrac{d}{dx}[y^2]=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$ whereas $\dfrac{d}{dx}[x^2]=2x$.

Although, when I plug in the first one to Symbolab, I get $\dfrac{d}{dx}[y^2]=0$.

I'm pretty sure Symbolab is way off as they're treating the $y$ as a constant?

I'm a math educator and I'm just trying to get a complete grasp of what it really means to take the derivative of a dependent variable with respect to an independent variable vs. taking the derivative of the independent variable with respect to itself, and why that corresponds to having to write $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at the end. I do get that $\dfrac{dx}{dx}=1$, so you can ignore that part.

Any helpful resources? Thanks!

Comment: Really you should write $y(x)$ so it's clearer that $y$ is a potentially nontrivial function of $x$; otherwise it's a little ambiguous.

Comment: Note that if you were given $(\mathrm d/\mathrm dx) a^2$ you almost certainly would think of it as $0$. When using the Leibniz notation there are conventions about the letters that matter.

Answer (score 1):

So when you evaluate something like $\frac{d}{dx} y^2$, you are assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$ or it can be expressed in relationship with x (like an implicit equation).

Because $y$ is dependent on $x$, when you change $x$ by an infinitesimal amount, $y$ must also change (unless the derivative is 0 at that point) by an amount that can be calculated by finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Most calculators and online tools, even ones equipped with a CAS, will not assume that another variables, including $y$, is in a relation with the variable being differentiated, in your case $x$. So symbolab is treating $y$ as an independent variable that is in no way constrained by changes in the value of $x$, hence $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. This is very similar to taking a partial derivative in a multivariable function, where all the dependent variables are independent of eachother.

Note that when you say $\frac{d}{dx} y^2=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$, you are assuming that $y$ is not independent of $x$ (unless $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$). Clearly, $x$ is dependent on itself, so $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$.